# $f : ]0, \infty[\to\mathbb{R}$ Prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0$ if $\lim_{x\to\infty} [f(x)+f'(x)] = 0$

Tags: real-analysis

I tried $ f(x)=\frac {f(x)e^x}{e^x} $ but now I'm stuck. How is it possible to apply the $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ - LHR?

Comment: Well, differentiate top and bottom, then simplify. What do you get?

Comment: Problem is: Are we allowed in the first place to apply l'Hopital? Of course $e^x\to \infty$, but $f(x)e^x$ might a priori oscillate between $0$ and $\infty$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen The rule applies as long as the denominator has infinite limit. (But, I see I misunderstood the question, now.)

Comment: @DavidMitra That (or the knowledge thereof) may depend on the literature used. For example, [some only encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) requires for $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ that either $\lim f(x)=\lim g(x)=0$ or $\lim|f(x)|=\lim |g(x)|=\infty$ ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I wonder if  L'Hôpital (or Bernoulli) realized the more general case holds.

Comment: $$\left|f(x)\right|=\left|\mathrm e^{-x}f(0)+\mathrm e^{-x}\int_0^x\mathrm e^u(f(u)+f'(u))\mathrm du\right|\leqslant\mathrm e^{-x}C_a+\mathrm e^{-x}\int_a^x\mathrm e^u\,\left|f(u)+f'(u)\right|\,\mathrm du\leqslant\ldots$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that does not use the l'Hôpital rule:

Fix $\epsilon >0$. Then, since $f(t)+f'(t)\to 0$ as $t\to +\infty$ we can find $R>0$ such that
$$
-\epsilon < f(t)+f'(t)<\epsilon
$$
if $t>R$. Multiplying the inequality above with $e^t$ and integrating from $R$ to $x>R$ (and using monotonicity of integrals), we get
$$
[-\epsilon e^t]_{t=R}^x<[f(t)e^t]_{t=R}^x<[\epsilon e^t]_{t=R}^x.
$$
This can be written
$$
-\epsilon + \epsilon e^{R-x}+f(R)e^{R-x}<f(x)<\epsilon -\epsilon e^{R-x}+f(R)e^{R-x}
$$
Since $e^{R-x}\to 0$ as $x\to +\infty$, we can find a $\tilde R$ such that
$$
-2\epsilon<f(x)<2\epsilon
$$
if $x>\tilde R$. Since this works for all $\epsilon >0$, it follows that $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to+\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are allowed to do that. To apply l'Hôpital's rule it is enough to have $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=\infty$. See for instance [this link](http://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=686).